# sendKey method in Appium sometime triggers a paste as well

Tags: java, android, appium

I have been working on learning Appium over the past few weeks, and I cannot get around one glaring bug.

Whenever I call sendKeys on a WebElement about 25% of the time it seems to long press and have the "paste" dialog bubble pop up. Then it pastes the last copied text from the clipboard, and sends the keys I told it to.

For example:

WebElement myElement = driver.find("email");
myElement.sendKeys("My text");

Android clipboard text: "This is some clipboard text"

Resulting input field:
"This is some clipboard textMy text"

I have tried clicking the input field directly before the send text in order to cancel out of the paste operation, but it seems to occur after the click. This makes me think the problem is inside the sendKeys method itself.

This problem seems to be very frequent in some inputs, while others hardly ever show this behavior (after about 40 tries the email field did it around 10 while the password field beyond it only did it once). The only thing that seems to work consistently is using the driver.sendKeyEvent method, which I believe uses the adb sendkey event directly.

After searching for several hours I have found only a few mentions of this bug. Is anyone familiar with it or know a good workaround for this?

Device: Galaxy Note Edge, 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issues, the work around i followed was once the keyboard pop's up  Navigate to **Keyboard Setting**, and ***turn off predictive text***. this will solve your problem

Comment: So when this happens to me, the text actually gets pastes without the keyboard ever popping up. The "paste" prompt shows up, and then the text is pasted

Comment: Turn off predictive text, you wont face this issue

Answer (score 0):

Turning off prediction text did not work for me.

I would recommend using .set_value instead(Python, probably .setValue for java). So far it is working without any issues.